# Bootstrap: I cant figure out why my site wont scroll

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I expand the accordion menu on my site it doesn't scroll. I've looked for any overflow:hidden styles and changed them to scroll. Any ideas?

```
http://139.62.63.205/~copteam11/ip/calendar.php
```

Comment: A tip (and my answer bellow): You are more likely to have better answers (and less -1) if you show some code and/or screen captures with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Man.. you have

```
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">...</div>

<div class="jumbotron" style="padding: 50px;">...</div>

<div id="eventDetails" style="display: none;">...</div>

<div id="here">...</div>
```

In

```
<div style="height: 200px;" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">...</div>
```

You didn't close this div:

```
<div style="height: 200px;" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

before:

```
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second *div*, the one with `class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"`, is surrounding the whole page (you probably forgot to close it right after the closing tag of the third div). This *div* has the class `navbar` which has `position:fixed`: that is why the page don't scroll.

Also, you should clean a little the html: the class `jumbotron` shouldn't be used in the body, also you may want to remove the `margin-left:20%` from the body, and the `width:60%` from the first div, since those two aren't having any effect in the layout.